# First day in AJAX in .NET MVC4, it doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Still trying to figure that out, here is my workflow:

1. once submit been clicked, the jquery will send a post request to call the method
2. method return a partial view
3. display on `<div id = "messageForm">...</div>` part

below is the form view:

```
//SignUp.cshtml:
<div id ="messageForm">

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignUp", "MVP", new AjaxOptions
{

    Confirm = "Are you sure you want to send this message?",
    HttpMethod = "Post",                                 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,                                 
    LoadingElementId = "loading",                                 
    UpdateTargetId = "messageForm"
})) {

      @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            messageModel

        </legend>

         <p>
            <input type ="submit" value ="Send Message" />
        </p>

    </fieldset>
```

here is the controller:

```
//MVPController
       [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult SignUp(MVCView model){
                return PartialView("_ThankYou");

            }

public ActionResult SignUp(){
                return View();
            }
```

Here is the partial view in view folder:

**ThankYou.cshtml:**

> ```
>     <h1>Thank you so much! We will contact you later</h1>
> ```

When testing it, I didn't see the confirm dialog and it redirect to the thank you page

Can anyone tell me why that happened?

Comment: Controller method is called SignUp, while the action in Html.AjaxForm is "ThankYou", are you sure it works?

Comment: I have added an answer assuming that you have an error? there's nothing that states this in the question?

Comment: Do you have anything funny going on in your markup (like nested forms) because it sounds like the form isn't being submitted asynchronously?

Comment: Have you referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in your layout/view? Because this file is required in order to the `Ajax.BeginForm` work...

Comment: close your #messageForm DIV prior to start a form. 
If you had it contain the form - thats a bad idea either as results will keep coming into self included DIVs.

Comment: @nemesv in my web config there is:　 <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

Comment: ＠Max Malyk　I tried, but it still refresh the page and show the partial view again. =[

Comment: @LifeScript you need to have a script include for 
    `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your layout or in your view. This file is not included by the default mvc project templates you need to add it manually and it has nothing to do with your web.config.

Comment: @nemesv Perfect point! It works because of you! would you like to make a good answer for that, so I can make it correct solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC 4 AJAX Submit Form not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066244/asp-net-mvc-4-ajax-submit-form-not-working)

Comment: @LifeScript, so there were two issues? wrong action name and no JS file?

Comment: @christiandev yes, I modified the action name and imported the js file, it works fine now!

Comment: posible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/15662750/138071

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ThankYou", "MVP", new AjaxOptions
```

I think this should be:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SignUp", "MVP", new AjaxOptions
```

The first string is the **Action name**, and you only have `SignUp` in the controller.

Comment: I changed that, but still the same problem

Comment: @LifeScript, what is `MVCView`? is the view strongly typed to this, I can't see much in the view? Also, are you missing any JS files for the ajax?